# what does [ ] mean in dart when used to wrap a parameter in a function

Tags: dart

I have been writing dart for a while and stumbled on this line of code:

```
String makeCommand(String executable, [List<String>? arguments]) {
      var result = executable;
      if (arguments == null) return result;
      return result + ' ' + arguments.join(' ');
}
```

the parameter `[List<String>? arguments]` confuses me because I am used to this `{List<String>? arguments}`. Can someone help me explain this?

Comment: This is covered by the [Functions > Parameters section of the Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dart, if you give a function like this `hello(int a, int b)`. You **have to provide both a and b value** if you are using this function or else you will get type error.

Now if the function is like this `hello(int a , [int b])`, the parameter b is **optional now**. You don't have to give the value of b and yet the function works when called by giving only one parameter.

**Difference between `hello(int a , [int b])` and `hello(int a , {int b})`**

Valid Function call for `hello(int a , [int b])`

- hello(1) //valid
- hello(1,2) //valid
- hello(1, b:2) // not valid

Valid Function call for `hello(int a , {int b})`

- hello(1) // not valid
- hello(1,2) // not valid
- hello(1, b:2) // valid

Comment: so how is **hello(int a , [int b])** different from **hello(int a , {int b})**

Comment: See the edited answer above. I have mentioned the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters enclosed in [] are optional positional parameters as shown in the [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

What that means is that you can write both `makeCommand("some executable name")` and `makeCommand("some executable name", some list of arguments)` without error